# GPU memory leakage when I load Keras models multi times

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a file `train.py` to train neural net model via `tensorflow.keras`, and the best model will be saved as `best_train.h5` according to the `train_loss`. The training time is about 7 days.

I have another file `test.py` to test the model saved during the running of `train.py`. In the `test.py` model, I load the `best_train.h5` every hour to see the test performance. The codes are as follows:

```
for i in range(7*24):
  time.sleep(1*60*60)
  model = tf.keras.models.load_model('best_train.h5')
  model.predict(test_data)
```

I found that every time I load `best-train.h5`, the occupied GPU memory will be increased. And after about 200 iterations, the GPU memory will be run out. OOM Errors will occur.

I know `tf.clear_session()` can free the GPU memory. But this command will clear all the sessions and graph. I is not what I wanted. Because in `test.py` there are still other models I hold.

Answer (score 3):

Since Keras shares the global session between all models. You can create a new graph and assign a session for prediction only:

```
self.graph = tf.Graph()
with self.graph.as_default():
   self.session = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)
   with self.session.as_default(): 
       # Load your model and preform prediction
```

Your GPU memory should be released as soon as you finish your prediction.